# How can I test Python Eve projections with pytest?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, eve

I am trying to somehow do a get request to testing flask client for Eve:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client():
    app = a.create_app()
    app.debug = True
    client = app.test_client()
    return client

def animal_mes_id(client):
    #res = client.get('/my_col?where={"_name": "animal"}')
    res = client.get('/my_col', query_string={"_name": "animal"})
    print(res.data)
    return res.data......['_id'] # Schematic way to show I just want to get the _id
```

I have not been able to neither one way, or the other in following lines

```
 #res = client.get('/my_col?where={"_name": "animal"}')
 res = client.get('/my_col', query_string={"_name": "animal"})
```

pass a  `--data-urlencode 'projection={"_id": 1}'` as it is [documented](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#projections)

I have tried things like:

```
client.get('/my_col?where={"_name": "animal"} --data-urlencode \'projection={"_id": 1}\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, so stupid from me. After further reading in docs I found it out:

This is the solution:

```
res = client.get('/my_col', query_string='where={"_name": "animal"}&projection={"_id": 1}')
```